# Is there something wrong with this Query? New to mysqli commands

Tags: mysqli

Is there something wrong with this query in mysqli? I converted it from mysql, worked perfectly then but now it doesn't

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM signed_out_students WHERE date = '$date6' AND time_in = '' order by time_out DESC");
```

This is how it fits into the actual code. I know that there is entries in the databse with the date of today but its not showing them? D:

```
else if (out == $display) {
    date_default_timezone_set('NZ');
$date6 = date('d.m.Y');
$result4 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM signed_out_students WHERE date = '$date6' AND time_in = '' order by time_out DESC");
  echo '<table border="0">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="70px"><h2>Date</h2>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td width="150px"><h2>Name</h2>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td width="90px"><h2>Form Class</h2>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td width="70px"><h2>Time Out</h2>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td width="70px"><h2>Time In</h2>';
  echo '</td>';

while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4))
  {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td><p>' . $row4['date'];
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td><p>' . $row4['name'];
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td><p>' . $row4['form_class'];
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td><p>' . $row4['time_out'];
  echo '</td>';
  echo '<td><p>' . $row4['time_in'];
  if ($row['time_in'] == "") { echo '-';}
  echo '</td>';

  }
  echo '</table>';
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Read up on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with this query in mysqli?

Yes, a lot.

1. You aren't checking for errors
2. You aren't using placeholders
3. You're using mysqli, while PDO have to be used instead.

Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Also, as a side note, your date have to be in `'Y-m-d'` format.

Answer (score -1):

remove the single quotes from the variable in the Query :

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM signed_out_students WHERE date = $date6 AND time_in = '' order by time_out DESC");
```